# node-sass not compiling with npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass, npm-scripts

So, I am reading [this article](https://css-irl.info/a-modern-front-end-workflow-part-1/) and following each of the steps described but when I am trying to run `npm run scss` I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

This is my .json file :

```
{
  "name": "new-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss",
    "serve": "browser-sync start --server --files 'dist/css/*.css, **/*.html'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  }
}
```

It does not create the dist file it's supposed to or doesn't do anything else.

Here is what I got.

`node -v v12.13.0
 npm -v 6.12.0`

Please let me know if you need any further information from my setup but it should be the exact same from the article.

Comment: the error says, "no input file was found". do you have a `.scss` file in the `src/scss` folder? it'd be helpful to see a repo.

Comment: Turns out I had a .css file in the folder. I forgot to type the "S" in front of it. Thanks for making to double-check this.